# SQL. Error: The multi-part identifier "inserted.*****" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Я хочу создать тригер, который будет обновлять значение одной таблицы в зависимости от того, какие данные мы добавили в  другую таблицу, и в результате обновления выполняет или не выполняет действие.

```
create trigger Arch_1Unit
on Sales After Insert as 

Update Product 
set Product.Count_ = Product.Count_ - inserted.Count_ 
where Product.Name = Name

if (Select Count_ from Product where inserted.Name = Product.Name) <= 0 

begin
INSERT INTO Archive select Product.Name, Product.Type, Count_, Prime_Cost, Manufacturer, Product.Saleprice from Product where Product.Name = inserted.Name

Update Product 
set Count_ = Count_ + 50
where Product.Name = inserted.Name

end;
```

Но я столкнулся с ошибкой:

> The multi-part identifier "inserted.Count_" could not be bound.

Не могу понять, почему я не могу использовать данные из виртуальной таблицы inserted.

Comment: inserted - это таблица, вставляться могут несколько строк одновременно и в триггере будет тоже несколько строк

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.